# Segmentation Error using strtok

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault, strtok, dereference

Trying to split a string using delimiter " " using strtok, but I am getting a segmentation error.

```
    char command[12];
    char *instruction;
    char *parameter_1;
    char *parameter_2;
    *instruction = strtok(command, " ,.-");
    *parameter_1 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    *parameter_2 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    write(1,parameter_1,sizeof(parameter_1));
```

at the point in th

EDIT:
As requested, compiler warnings.  Not using int anywhere, so confused.

```
shell.c:51:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
shell.c:52:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
shell.c:53:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Command: abd def ghj
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
int prompt() {
    // Get Input
    char inputData[256];
    int rid;
    rid = read(0,inputData,256);

    // Strip input
    char command[rid];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<=rid-2; i++) {
        command[i] = inputData[i];
    }
    command[rid-1] = '\0';

    // Debug
    //  printf("\n-%c-%i\n",command[10],(int)sizeof(command));
    //  write(1,command,sizeof(command));

    if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
        break;
    }

    char *instruction;
    char *parameter_1;
    char *parameter_2;
    instruction = strtok(command, " ");
    parameter_1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    parameter_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    write(1,instruction,sizeof(instruction));
    //write(1,parameter_2,sizeof(parameter_2));
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled. Paste compilable example, there may be subtleties not shown in partial code snippet. Https://sscce.org

Comment: Additionally, the code snippet shown derefererences uninitialized pointers, which usually crashes right away.

Comment: Yup, turn on compiler warnings, then come back when you have eliminated all warnings ;)

Comment: strtok() return char *, but you dereference your `char *` which gives you char. So you assign char * to char variable. Also, you dereference uninitialized pointer that way, and that's first step do disaster.

Comment: Ok, so re: the pointers, should I point them all to nullptr to start with?

Comment: No, don't dereference them before strtok() returns in the first place

Comment: So  that's all the compiler warnings gone now, just stuck with it outputting two pieces of the delimited string now.

Comment: Post working code that we can compile and run.

Comment: code posted, also on github at http://github.com/samheather/octo-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix as follows:

```
char command[12];
char *instruction;
char *parameter_1;
char *parameter_2;
instruction = strtok(command, " ,.-");
parameter_1 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
parameter_2 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
write(1,parameter_1,sizeof(parameter_1));
```

(Removed the *)

Comment: Tested, this still prints defghi when command contains 'abc def ghi\0'

Comment: Replace `sizeof()` with `strlen()`, and worry about a newline for the output.

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in comments:

```
*instruction = strtok(command, " ,.-");
*parameter_1 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
*parameter_2 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
```

should be relaced with

```
instruction = strtok(command, " ,.-");
parameter_1 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
parameter_2 = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
```

Also `sizeof(instruction)` doesn't return number of characters( it's not an array) but size of pointer to char (that's what instruction, param_1, param_2 really are) on your machine.
As answer to OP comment:
`write()` or `fwrite()` work on bytes, without checking its meanings so they don't stop on `'\0'`.
`fprintf()`, `fputs()` are prepared to work on strings so they check for `'\0'` char to stop.

Comment: it has been - see code sample included above.

Comment: Ok, but this is still really odd then as it prints out defghi, when def is a string with a null character at the end after the f, so shouldn't it stop after this null character?

Comment: No, write works on bytes, not chars. And `\0' is just a null byte. Functions working on arrays of chars(like printf("%s") or puts look for it, functions working on bytes don't look what that byte means. It's just portion of 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 0):

command is a string literal, it is in ROM. copy it to a local variable maybe using memcpy()  and then use it in strtok().

Comment: I don't see `command` as a string literal in the code.  It is defined as: `char command[rid];`